# What does Laravel Elixir use for minification?

Tags: laravel, minify, laravel-elixir

The documentation is vague about the compressor used for both CSS and JS:

```sh
# Run all tasks and minify all CSS and JavaScript...
gulp --production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Elixir is built on top of [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) -

To minify CSS and JS it uses the [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat), [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) and [gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) gulp plugins.